# Draw (tree) diagram in HTML

Tags: html, diagram

I want to have a diagram in a web page, that looks something like this (from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFA_Euro_2012#Knockout_stage)):

[image]

(the details don't matter too much - it mustn't be a binary tree, and not necessarily with 3 levels)

I currently use a (pre-calculated) table for which most of the borders are transparent, but this is ugly programming, and difficult to maintain. How would I draw such a diagram programatically? I don't want to use a `canvas`because I need to put `html` elements in the boxes, mainly drop-down lists and links.

I was thinking of positioning the boxes manually through `CSS`, and drawing the lines with elements like the following (for an horizontal line):

```
<p style="border: 2px solid black; height: 0px; width: ...;  top:...; right:...;"/>
```

Is this the way to go? Is there a less ad-hocway of drawing lines?

Comment: what language are u using for front view ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think DIV-oriented webpage with position: css element is the best approach.